# Remove Parentheses () in URL string

Tags: ios, string

I have this string:

```
dataSourceURL = URL(string:"https://api.abc.com/api/p4/products?pid=uid8225&format=json&offset=\(count)&limit=20")
```

when I do `print(dataSourceURL)` I get:

https://api.abc.com/api/p4/products?pid=uid8225&format=json&offset=Optional(0)&limit=20

How can I remove `()`? Please suggest.

I want to get

```
https://api.abc.com/api/p4/products?pid=uid8225&format=json&offset=0&limit=20
```

Comment: count is optional .. so unwrap it like `\(count!)`

Comment: @G S optional values need to be forced unwrap using optional Binding .

Comment: thanks El Captain v2.0, i have unwrapped it and it is working fine now , as mentioned i have declared as \(count!) and it is working fine , thanks a lot , much appreciated

Comment: @GS if  count value is nil then please crash .. avoid forced unwrap

Comment: Is it really necessary that the variable `count` is an optional? In almost all cases there is no reason to declare scalar types like `Int`, `Double`, `Bool` as optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can unwrap the value.

I would recommend using `??` as it will provide a default value and avoid the crash if it finds a nil.

```
let dataSourceURL = URL(string:"https://api.abc.com/api/p4/products?pid=uid8225&format=json&offset=\(count ?? 0)&limit=20")
```

it prints:

```
https://api.abc.com/api/p4/productspid=uid8225&format=json&offset=0&limit=20
```

Another way to do it is:

```
let dataSourceURL = URL(string:"https://api.abc.com/api/p4/products?pid=uid8225&format=json&offset=\(count!)&limit=20")
```

Be aware if `count` value is nil, the application will crash in this case.